# How do set time inside bootstrap widget

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I am using this [Widget](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/timepicker/examples) in my angular application . In my `appmodule.ts`

```
  import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
  imports:[NgbModule.forRoot(),....]
```

Widget is shown in UI but time is not set.[image]

```
      //inside component.ts 
      meridian = true;
      timePickerFormat:any ;
      //inside constructor
      this.timePickerFormat = {hour: 13, minute: 30};
```

And inside html `<ngb-timepicker [(ngModel)]="timePickerFormat" [meridian]="meridian"></ngb-timepicker>`

Comment: Looks good, should work. Could you please provide your Component ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try timePickerFormat instead of this.timePickerFormat in component.ts?

Here is the working plunkr link http://plnkr.co/edit/waq1Ksq6Cf01eqYFOgwC?p=streamer

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-timepicker-basic',
  templateUrl: 'src/timepicker-basic.html'
})
export class NgbdTimepickerBasic {
  timePickerFormat = {hour: 13, minute: 30};
  meridian=true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try [ngModel] not [(ngModel)], i think it's an issue in ng-bootstrap timepicker

```
<ngb-timepicker [ngModel]="timePickerFormat" [meridian]="meridian"></ngb-timepicker>
```